# Run ajax call in parent and call success in child using Vue.js

Tags: ajax, vue.js

What is the best way to make an ajax call in the parent and then run the success function within the child?

For example:

//Parent

```
var ajax = myAjaxCall.fetch(); //returns a promise
```

//Component

```
ajax.success({... //etc.
```

Also the component should watch if ajax is run again sp it can update again if parents makes that call again.

Comment: Send the Promise to the child [as a prop](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props).

Comment: With props you have to send them as an attribute.  Is there a way without sending the attribute? Like making a global variable in parent?

Comment: That would not be the "[best way](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)".

Comment: Why not just send the result of the ajax to the child thru props?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs) attribute to the child component and then call the child's method from the parent component's scope:

In the child component:

```
methods: {
  successHandler(promise) {
    promise.success(() => { });
  }
}
```

In the parent component:

```
methods: {
  fetch() {
    var ajax = myAjaxCall.fetch();
    this.$refs.child.successHandler(ajax);
  }
}
```

In the template:

```
<child ref="child"></child>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent template:

```
<div>
  <button @click="executeRequest">Execute</button>
  <child-component :result="result">
</div>
```

Parent script:

```
data: {
  result: null
},
methods: {
  executeRequest () {
    // execute AJAX request using axios, fetch, whatever
    this.result = response
  }
}
```

Child template:

```
<div>
  <div v-if="result">Call was completed and result was: {{result}}</div>
</div>
```

Child script:

```
props: {
  result: Object // or string, int, whatever the AJAX request response returns
}
```